# How to slide aside from left to right by using animate function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have positioned **aside** as **absolute** `top: 0px;` and `left: -300px;`.
It's width is 300px, I want to slide it from left to right as It can come to this position, `left: 0px;` and by clicking on button vice-versa it can toggle between position `left: -300px;` to `left: 0px;` through animate function in jQuery.

This is what I have done right now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#controls").click(function(){
        $("#hiddenSideBar").animate({left: '0px'});
    })
});
```

Now, the **hiddenSideBar** is sliding from left to right once clicking on button but when clicking again on button nothing happens and this **hiddenSideBar** remains visible in body.

Here, is the demo.
[demo of my issue on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wqzse7k/3/)

Sorry, if I couldn't explain it clearly? But this is what actually I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a class toggle, it is more manageable IMO.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#controls").click(function(){
        $("#hiddenSideBar").toggleClass("show");
    })
});
```

**CSS**

```
#hiddenSideBar {
   transition: left .3s;
   left: -300px;
   ...
}

#hiddenSideBar.show {
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a demo on jsFiddle to verify

Comment: this is the demo bro

Comment: @AdnanMemon you didn't fully implement my solution - here is a working fork: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/L9s5977f/

Comment: Hey Man you are too good bro, thank u so much, its working... :)